Name of a sci-fi book/series about a young boy raised to fight for his life? Mix of Hunger Games and Ender’s Game
I read this story in the last few years. It was published within the last 7 or so.
The setting is a military-style encampment with tents and cots for all the children. Each was allowed to bring one item with them to the camp. The boy is placed in a “troop” of other young children. At some point when the children are first brought to the camp they are given the chance to choose their weapon. Each week they have to fight (sometimes to the death) against other young boys (and rarely girls) their age in a ring. The ring is a dirt pit surrounded by bleachers for other children to watch the fights. One of the other children in their troop is a mute boy. He is one of the most distinct and identifiable characters. As they get older the troop advances and receives better living conditions. They earn points from each battle and go up in status. Additionally a girl joins their group later on as their member number goes down too much (her main weapons are throwing knives). At this point the troop chooses a name for themselves and we start seeing conflict and alliances between theirs and other “troops”. Troops can request their fight with a specific troop which leads to to more strategy of who will fight for them. Eventually they get the chance to seek a sponsor. Sponsors are rich “watchers” of sorts as the fights were televised in a way. If you had a sponsor you could get medicine or better weapons (not unlike The Hunger Games). The other fighting characters would go watch and learn strategies from the fights. The overarching goal was to get high enough in the fighting levels that at a certain point you no longer have to fight anymore. It is the top 5 or so people that don’t have to fight anymore.

"Ender's Game if everyone had real guns"
